# How to read CSV file based on first letter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a CSV file that is simply a list of usernames like "jsmith, mdoe, smae, etc."

I need to read this file in Powershell and add them to different AD groups based on their first letter.  So "jsmith" would need to go in group J, "mdoe" would need to go in group M, and "smae" would need to go in group S.

How can I read this data and separate it based on the first letter?

Comment: Did you make any attempt to find your own solution? If so, please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file, then add to the group based on .SubString(0,1).

If you have a header line you will want to add `Select -Skip 1 |` before the `%{` loop.

```
GC file.csv | %{Add-ADGroupMember ($_.SubString(0,1)) $_}
```

**Edit:** Ok, you want it broken down so I'll do my best.

`GC file.csv` - GC is short for Get-Content. That will read the file, and pass the contents along the pipe 1 line at a time.

`%{` - That is short for `ForEach{`, so the things in the script block `{...}` will be performed for each line.

`Add-ADGroupMember ($_.SubString(0,1)) $_` - The command adds a user account to an AD group. The first argument `($_.SubString(0,1))` is the group that you are adding to. What it reads is `$_` (the current line that is being processed) `.SubString(0,1)` means that it is taking a part of the string, starting at character 0 (the first character), and only grabbing 1 character, thus the `(0,1)` part of it. And the second argument `$_` is the entire line that is being processed, which should just be the user name according to what you said.
`}` - That closes the ForEach loop.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Ok, but how do I do this by the letter?  So how would I tell it to add to a group if the first letter is A or B or C.

Comment: That is what this does. It finds the first letter and adds the user to a group who's name is that letter. So jdoe is added to group J, and msmith is added to group M

Answer (score 0):

$a="foobar"

$a[0]

This will give you the first character of the string.